# Valgrind shows "Invalid read of size 8" while reading file

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, valgrind

I have a simple method which is searching for exact values in the vectors (data obtained from file) or interpolating the not existing once. I have been running this program many times before and it was working and suddenly it's not. 
The code:

```
double  Integr::F(double x_val, double q2_val){

    int i=0;
    bool interpolate_x=0, interpolate_q=0;

    vector<double>::iterator it = begin(x_f);
    for(; it != end(x_f) ; it += 201){

        if(*it == x_val){
            interpolate_x = 0;
            break;
        }
        else if(*it > x_val){
            interpolate_x = 1;
            break;
        }
        i += 201;
    }

    it = begin(q2)+i;
    for(; it != end(q2) ; ++it){

        if(*it == q2_val){
            interpolate_q = 0;
            break;
        }
        else if(*it > q2_val){
            interpolate_q = 1;
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    double f1, f2;
    if(interpolate_x){

        f1 = Interpolate::interpolate(f[i], f[i-201], x_f[i], x_f[i-201], x_val);
        f2 = Interpolate::interpolate(f[i-1], f[i-202], x_f[i-1], x_f[i-202], x_val);
        if(!interpolate_q) return f1;
        else{
            return Interpolate::interpolate(f1, f2, q2[i], q2[i-1], q2_val);
        }
    }
    if(interpolate_q){

        return Interpolate::interpolate(f[i], f[i-1], q2[i], q2[i-1], q2_val);
    }
    else return f[i];
}
```

Firstly, valgrind shows:

```
==4138== Invalid read of size 8
==4138== at 0x4021C8: Integr::F(double, double) (Integr.cpp:81)
```

and it points to the last line in the above method:

```
else return f[i];
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

[EDIT]
Method reading from file:

```
void Data::read_File() {

    if(file.good() == true){

        double tmp1, tmp2, tmp3;
        int i=0;
        while(!file.eof()) {
            ++i;
            file >> tmp1;
            file >> tmp2;
            file >> tmp3;
            x.push_back(tmp1);
            q.push_back(tmp2);
            f.push_back(tmp3);
            cout << i << endl;
        }
        file.close();

    } else cout << "Access denied! \n";
}
```

Comment: `for(; it != end(x_f) ; it += 201)` running past the end of the vector seems a likely candidate

Comment: `i += 201;` I would suggest you to remove magic numbers from your code and replace them with constants.

Comment: `bool interpolate_x = 0`?? Possibly more importantly here:     `vector<double>::iterator it = begin(x_f);` - what is x_f? This code snippet isn't enough to be going on with.

Comment: Small suggestion: drop `it`, get the size of the vectors and index with `i`.  Also, you can attach a debugger to valgrind and check `i`and `f`, see http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver

Comment: @M.M I used your advice and now I do not get any error from valgrind but my program suspends while reading file (I checked that it's getting to the last line in the file)

Comment: @TomTanner: x_f is just a vector with the data read from the file. This program is really long, I wanted just to show the essential part which brings me trouble

Comment: @stefaanv I dropped the iterator and used the size of the vectors but my program is still freezing

Comment: Any luck with the debugger?

Comment: @stefaanv: also freezing

Comment: I've added the reading file method because now the program stops at this step, like it's getting to the end of the file, but never meeting the eof...

Comment: What is `f`, it is nowhere declared?

Comment: It's a vector declared in both classes. In class `Data` I am putting the data from file into this vector and then I convey it to the class `Integr` using getter

Comment: The better way to read file is `while(file >> tmp1 >> tmp2 >>tmp3)` with `file.good()` the last line can be read in twice.